# Why is my aws ebs volume figure so high reaching above free tier.

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

Ive been playing around with aws elastic beanstalk for a month now. Hardly any usage. Just testing small things every other day. When i see my billing i see that ebs volume figure going above free tier. I'm not sure what i could have done to prevent it since i'm not using it much. Also, its starting to worry me about the future where i get some user usage. I feel like this figure will skyrocket and incur a lot of unexpected charges. I know this could be an open ended question but are there tips and tricks to keep myself from being overcharged on ebs? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. Make sure that at the end of day you not only terminate instances, but also delete all unneeded Volumes and Snapshots
2. [Create a Billing Alarm to Notify You if Your Usage Exceeds the Free Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html)
3. Take look at your [Billing & Cost Management Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/), it may give you some more insight